# ASP.Net MVC one link should return multiple pages(Views)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My page has print action link for which when user clicks, there are 3 pages(views) that should be printed(launched) and all should be loaded in 3 new windows or tabs...

How can I achieve this in asp.net mvc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since one HTTP request can't have more than one response, you'll need to send three requests.  You can do this in JavaScript.

If you have your link as something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="openThreeWindows">Open Three Windows</a>
```

Then you can add a click event in JavaScript (assuming jQuery since that's standard with ASP.NET):

```
$(function () {
    $('#openThreeWindows').on('click', function () {
        window.open('@Url.Action("FirstAction", "FirstController")', '_blank');
        window.open('@Url.Action("SecondAction", "SecondController")', '_blank');
        window.open('@Url.Action("ThirdAction", "ThirdController")', '_blank');
    });
});
```

This should open three new windows or tabs (that part is up to the browser) for the three actions specified by calls to `Url.Action()`.  Naturally, you can use whatever overload of `Url.Action()` you like, or build the URLs in any other way that you like.